# Navigation bar overlap status bar after push

Tags: ios, uikit, uinavigationbar, statusbar, overlap

Structure: NavigationController -> VC1 -> VC2

VC1 needs to show or hide status bar programmatically, it's controlled by `statusBarHidden`

```
var statusBarHidden = false {
        didSet {
            setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return false
    }
```

VC2 also added the following code:

```
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
        return false
    }
```

If `statusBarHidden` is **not changed** before `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC2, animated: true)`, status bar **WILL NOT** overlap navigation bar in VC2.

But once `statusBarHidden` is set to `true`, even it is set back to `false`, status bar will overlap navigation bar in VC2, BTW, it's the same with Storyboard Segue. But it works fine on iPhones with notch, such as iPhone X, iPhone 11.

[image]

I had tried to set a fix height, but the actual height seemed to be not effected, navigation bar always kept a certain height than 64.

```
navBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:20, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:64)
```