# SwiftUI - Overlapping Navigation bar In multi-controller hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**I'm trying to understand why ScrollView inside a multi-controller hierarchy is no longer animating NavigationBar on scrolling.**

Given that I have the following setup:

`SwiftUI` View:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

That Lives in the following hierarchy:

`UINavigationController->UIHostingController->SwiftUIView`

Everything works as expected, as you can observe here (NavigationBar opacity changes as a user scrolls):

[image: No Contoller]

But when I change the hierarchy and add another controller in between, it seems like ScrollView is losing "focus" for NavigationBar:

`UINavigationController->UIViewController->UIHostingController->SwiftUIView`

[image: With Controller]

I assume that given that ScrollView is no longer at the top of the hierarchy, it loses control over the original NavigationBar

**Here's demo, if anyone wants to play** - https://github.com/ignotusverum/NavigationTesting

---

PS:

There are different approaches that I can take to make NavigationBar visible; for example, adding `.padding(.top)` seems to help with that, but NavigationBar is not reacting to the Scrolling action:

[image: Padding]

Other questions that I researched:

- [SwiftUI Navigation title overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66887246/swiftui-navigation-title-overlapping)
- [Navigation bar overlap status bar after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64413385/navigation-bar-overlap-status-bar-after-push)

Comment: Is there a reason to embed the view in UIKit? Things would probably be much easier with plain swiftui.

Comment: Yeah, mixing UIKit and SwiftUI navigation bars / scroll is always kind of sketchy